# Sending a SMS with PHP, without an Third Party API

Tags: php, http, mobile

I know this question has been asked many times and many would just press report button before reading this, but the reason why I created another question for the same question is that:

I readed around 20 stackoverflow pages about this topic and readed all or almost all the links they linked to and all of them mentioned either a Third Party Plugin or the following method:

> 10 digit number@carrier

so for example it could be

> 3855550168@vtext.com

but I tried using that method with my cellphone and carrier, but it didn't work.

So my question would be how to achieve such task? or If the method mentioned above works, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: 3 options: carrier, third party api, or the skill to connect your phone to your computer and use that

Answer (score 2):

Its an email to SMS gateway. Not all carriers support this and some also allow you to switch to something other than a phone number as your address.

If you want to support all carriers, you need to use an API. You can use email if your users are on a set of supported carriers.